# why do a bowler use a white marker disc?

Tags: cricket

why do a bowler use a white marker disc? I have seen that a bowler put a white disc on ground before taking run ups.So why do they use it?

Answer (score 7):

They use it to mark the start of their run up without the need to scuff the grass or use spray paint.